# iOS Facebook SDK - Best Practices?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I was wondering what the "best practice" guidelines are for using the Facebook iOS SDK.

Specifically - I have several forms that use the Facebook SDK.
My initial instinct as an OOP programmer was to create a "FacebookManager" class under my data-access-layer which handles all Facebook activity.
Unfortunately since Facebook iOS SDK uses delegates and async methods, this is not so helpful since any other module using FacebookManager would have to pass in delegates for all responses anyway.

Then I figured that each ViewController would be a FBRequestDelegate by itself and handle all Facebook responses.

So, how do you do it in your app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've done is to create a FacebookManager as you suggested.  This manager becomes the FBRequestDelegate.  Now I prefer blocks to the delegation model so all my FacebookManager methods are block based.

Here is what my post to a user's wall method looks like

```
- (void)postToUserWall:(NSDictionary*)postDictionary withCompleteHandler:(void(^)(id result, NSError* error))block {


  if( [facebook_ isSessionValid] ) {
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [postDictionary mutableCopy];
    [params setObject:facebook_.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    FBRequest* request = [facebook_ requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:[postDictionary mutableCopy] andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    [[request params] setObject:block forKey:@"result"];
  }

}
```

Then on a success or error I just execute the block

```
- (void)processRequest:(FBRequest*)request withResult:(id)result andError:(NSError*)error {
  NSDictionary* params = [request params];
  if( [request params] != nil && [params objectForKey:@"result"] != nil ) {
    void(^completeBlock)(id result,NSError* error) = [params objectForKey:@"result"];
    completeBlock(result, nil);
  }
}


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
  [self processRequest:request withResult:result andError:nil];
}


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  [self processRequest:request withResult:nil andError:error];
}
```

I wish there was a better way to deal with the block but that's the best one I have found so far.  Is this the best way to do it? Probably not but that's what I currently use and it seems to be ok, keeping all the FB interaction away from my View Controllers.

Note all the code here assumes ARC that's why there are no releases

Comment: Why aren't the 2 last lines in the PostToWall function reversed? You run the request and THEN add the block as a parameter to it?
I don't get it...

Comment: My understanding is that the request gets prepped up and it is not executed until the next time runloop is run.  That's why it looks that the request should go out before the block is added however in practice it is executed on the next go of the run loop after the block is added

Comment: I ended up using your example. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting way to wrap their async framework into a block. +1. However, were you able to wrap the login method (authorize) into a block model? The FBSessionDelegate methods do not return any objects...

Comment: Looks like someone else implemented a block login by storing the block to an ivar on the manager. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561421/any-way-to-have-completionhandler-style-syntax-using-facebook-authorize-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook manager, basically a wrapper over Facebook sdk is the way to go. Here are a few tips on how to manage it.

1) Modify Facebook SDK's protocol definitions and make the ones you don't need as optional so you won't have to implement them.

2) Handle all session activities, login/logout, delegates, protocols, etc in this manager class. In other words, this manager implements all protocols defined by the Facebook sdk.

3) Define your own protocol in manager class and make all protocol methods optional, so every view controller can define what it actually needs.

4) Some helpful wrappers would be useful, like,

```
- (void) postToFriend: (Record*) f_record withMessage: (NSString*) message;
- (void) resumeSession; // checks, resumes session, extend token, or report error
```

5)  It would be easy to add wrappers if you need more features for your viewControllers

A lot of open source code is available (search github) but a custom manager class is not difficult to write and can be easily ported to other projects.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We have built a fairly extensive library ready to use for facebook integration. See here:

https://github.com/RIKSOF/three20/tree/development/src/extThree20Facebook

Its an extension on Three20 framework. You can easily modify this library to be independent of Three20, if you like.

We basically have defined objects for each Graph API object. JSON returned from the Graph API is read in to these objects.